# Should functions take extra arguments for the sake of testing?

Tags: python, testing

I am writing tests for a program I intend to write that checks for certain lines in configuration files.

For example, the program might check that the line: AllowConnections- 
is contained in the file SomeFile.conf.

My function stub does not take any arguments because I know the file that I am going to be checking.

I am trying to write a tests for this function that check the behavior for different SomeFile.conf files, but I don't see how I could do this. It is possible to change SomeFile.conf in the setup and teardown test functions, but this seems like a bad way to test. Should I change the function so that it can accept a file argument just for the sake of testing?

Comment: You could provide a default argument for the parameter for the file, or create two versions of the function: one with parameter, and one without, calling the other with the right argument.

Comment: You can't overload methods in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you test, and the code you run should be same.

I do not recommend using a filename, because now you are dealing with (in one function) opening the file - and the errors associated with that part, and then confirming the file format (the actual purpose of the function).

It sounds to me that your function's job is to check if the file's contents contain a specific string. So, this function should take any type of content element (an iterable) and then as long as the key string is not found, the function should return None/False/Fail condition - and your test should check for that.

Answer (score 0):

It would be quite possible to define the function as

```
def checkline_in_file(filename="SomeFile.conf"):
```

Using a default value for the filename. In testing it can be overridden. In production you don't need to give it an argument.

Later on, when phb decides that all file extensions must have exactly 3 characters, it is a one character change.